# What are default rules to connect cold part to protective ground?

Tags: high-voltage, circuit-protection, earth

I have a device, what have hot and cold part. I want to protect cold circuit what contains user interface from HV leaks or breakouts.

In professional PCB im frequently seen cold-common connected to hot-PE thru HV capacitor. But as i know, this is for noise filtering.
So what is best praticles to connect cold part of device to PE?

Can i connect it directly? But what if user connects PE to PEN network, in this case device become more dangerous than without PE at all.

PS im located in RU, so it is EU standards.

Comment: what do you mean by hot and cold? It's not about temperature, is it?

Comment: Cold is neutral :D

Comment: The solution is "don't connect them".   Use a galvanically isolated power supply, problem solved.  This isn't an issue, most power supplies will be galvanically isolated from the power source.  NOT ALL.   A variac is a great example of one that isn't.   There should be no metal-to-metal connections between your power source and the circuit you're working with.  Let it float.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio I am not sure. From the context, I interpret it as an isolated AC-to-DC converter where 'hot' refers to the AC side, and 'cold' refers to the DC side.

Comment: Uhmm probably you are right. I'll amend the answer. Hot and cold are usually phase and neutral

Comment: @kyleb There are exception. The control system under the machinery directive common return (i.e. the 24V ground in most cases) *has* to be grounded to trip the fuse if something in the control part touch the chassis (grounded). It's device directive dependant. 99% of instrumentation has it floating for convenience however

Comment: @kyleb But PC has no, as for example. PCs common is connected to PE. And many home devices too. Isolated converted gives no warranty what another part of circuit is not failed somehow. I have much of parts like this in my device (relay blocks and etc), high voltage divided only for a few mm and varnish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EU phase and neutral (proper names for hot and cold) are considered both live and dangerous. In fact many EU plugs are not even polarised (here in Italy *no* consumer plug is polarised!).

So just treat both conductors as primary. Depending on your kind of equipment (I may wrong but I think it's always) bonding the neutral to PE could be explicitly forbidden.

As you said it all depends on the kind of earthing system is in use. In fact with the Italian system (TT and mandatory RCDs) bonding neutral to PE almost guarantee a trip. Or directly the breaker if you plug in the 'wrong' way.

EDIT: I could have got the question wrong. The answer before still applies *however* if you as 'cold' mean the secondary (insulated side) of the circuit:

*It really depends on what you want to do* and the directive you are following. For many applications you can just float all the isolated circuit at whatever potential it want (no need for ground ties since there can't be a fault current)

- For EMC you could want to extablish a Functional Ground, like the capacitors you mentioned;
- Under some standards like the EN 60204-1 for fault protection you *must* ground the secondary common return (9.4.3.1.2
  Method a) – Earthed control circuits fed by transformers)
- Medical devices have a crazy list of requirements for grounding and insulation (since they often put wires on naked and sick people, essentially)

Comment: Yes, under cold i mean low voltage part of device.